# How to use ggplot2 aes_string() with cut() in a for loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to loop over some continuous variables to create ggplots. This works fine with `aes_string`, but I've now tried 1000s of variations to include `cut` in the call to generate bins of the variable. But it either fails or the loop does not work and it uses the same variable value within `aes` all the time.

In my actual data, I tried to calculate the `breaks` for `cut` beforehand similar to `cut_interval(n = 6)`, as each variable has a different range, but this also did not help.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(diamonds)
diamonds <- head(diamonds, 200)

# select some numeric categories to loop over
categories <- names(diamonds)[c(1,5,6)]

# this works fine in a loop
plot_list <- list()
for (category in categories){
plot_list[[category]] <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], aes_string(fill = category), colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], aes_string(fill = category, colour = "price"), pch = 21)
}
plot_list

# together with cut(), it does not work anymore
cut_plot_list <- list()
for (category in categories){
  cut_plot_list[[category]] <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], aes_string(fill = cut(category, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf)), colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], aes_string(fill = cut(category, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf))), colour = "price"), pch = 21)
}
# fails: 'x' must be numeric

# this gives identical plots without fill
cut_plot_list <- list()
for (category in categories){
  cut_plot_list[[category]] <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], aes(fill = cut(get(category), breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf)), colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], aes(fill = cut(get(category), breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf)), colour = price), pch = 21)
}
cut_plot_list
```

How do I combine a for loop (or lapply) in ggplot2 with dynamic discrete values for the variable?

EDIT:

without a for loop for one variable I would call it like this:

```r
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
  geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], aes(fill = table), colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
  geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], aes(fill = table , colour = price), pch = 21)

# or with the binned values
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
  geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], aes(fill = cut(table, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf))), colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
  geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], aes(fill = cut(table, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf)) , colour = price), pch = 21)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use non-standard evaluation :

```
library(ggplot2)

apply_fun <- function(category) {
   ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
       geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], 
           aes(fill = cut(!!sym(category), breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf))), 
           colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
       geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], 
           aes(fill = cut(!!sym(category), breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 10, 20, Inf)) , 
           colour = price), pch = 21)
}
```

and then call for each `categories`

```
plot_list <- lapply(categories, apply_fun)
```

---

To cut data into `n` intervals we can do

```
apply_fun <- function(category, n) {

  breaks = seq(min(diamonds[[category]]), max(diamonds[[category]]), length.out = n)
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = z)) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color == "E", ], 
               aes(fill = cut(!!sym(category), breaks = breaks)), 
               colour = "grey50", pch = 21) +
    geom_point(data = diamonds[diamonds$color != "E", ], 
               aes(fill = cut(!!sym(category), breaks = breaks) , 
               colour = price), pch = 21)
}
```

Apply the function with

```
plot_list <- lapply(categories, apply_fun, n = 6)
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! Is there a way to also provide an object as input to the `cut(breaks=)` argument? I tried instead `fill = cut_interval(!!sym(category), n = 6))` inside the call to have fitting bins for each category, but this will give me a total of 12 bins, each 6 for `color == "E"` and `color != "E"`. I would define the breaks before the ggplot call, but as they are no breaks, I can't use `!!sym()`

Comment: @crazysantaclaus I have updated the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: that is perfect! could you explain to me, why `breaks` as variable works without using `!!sym`, but `category` does not? I will also edit your code slightly, as I forgot to use a `pch` here which can actually display `fill`

Comment: @crazysantaclaus `sym` is used only for columns and not for values like `breaks`.